# Destructuring instead of .bind() doesn't work in an Arrow Monad comprehension

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

According to Arrow's Javadoc there are three ways of binding over a monad:

````
/**
 * All possible approaches to running [Kind] in the context of [Fx]
 *
 * ```
 * fx {
 *   val one = just(1).bind() // using bind
 *   val (two) = just(one + 1) // using destructuring
 *   val three = !just(two + 1) // yelling at it
 * }
 * ```
 */
````

The first one and the last one work fine however for some reason destructuring doesn't, why?

In the next sample you can see I'm using destructuring, `val (j) = helloJoey().k(),) but that value is interpreted as a` Mono` instead of a String.

```
class HelloServiceImpl : HelloService {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    override fun helloEverybody(): Mono<out String> {
        return MonoK.monad().fx.monad {
            val (j) = helloJoey().k()
            val a = !Mono.zip(helloJohn(), helloMary()).map { "${it.t1} and ${it.t2}" }.k()
            "$j and $a"
        }.fix().mono

    }

    override fun helloJoey(): Mono<String> {
        return Mono.defer {
            logger.info("helloJoey()")
            sleep(2000)
            logger.info("helloJoey() - ready")
            Mono.just("hello Joey")
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    }

    override fun helloJohn(): Mono<String> {
        return Mono.defer {
            logger.info("helloJohn()")
            sleep(5000)
            logger.info("helloJohn() - ready")
            Mono.just("hello John")
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    }

    override fun helloMary(): Mono<String> {
        return Mono.defer {
            logger.info("helloMary()")
            sleep(5000)
            logger.info("helloMary() - ready")
            Mono.just("hello Mary")
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    }

}

fun main() {
    val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(1)
    HelloServiceImpl().helloEverybody().subscribe {
        println(it)
        countDownLatch.countDown()
    }
    countDownLatch.await()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem and why we're moving away from this approach. They're marked as deprecated [here](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow-core/blob/ab5690b9f7f07933de5d9d4c951bbcaca26aeaef/arrow-core-data/src/main/kotlin/arrow/typeclasses/suspended/BindSyntax.kt#L17).

What happens is, a `MonoK` is a data class for which the destructure operator is already defined as returning the wrapped `Mono`. When used inside an `fx` block this destructuring takes precedence over the one defined on `BindSyntax`. Check and see if hinting your expected type works, otherwise use `invoke` or `bind` instead.